# My bootstrap modal won't close upon clicking the 'x' or Close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, bootstrap-modal

For some reason, my bootstrap modal won't close.  I can preview the image in the modal just fine but when I try to close it, it doesn't work.

I tried to put `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>` on top of the existing `<div className="modal-dialog"></div>` but if I do that, then the modal won't even appear upon clicking `Preview Image` image button.

What am I doing wrong & how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            prevImgURL: '',
            imgPrev: false
        };
        this.imageChange = this.imageChange.bind(this);
    }

    imagePreview = (newPostImageBool) => {
        this.setState({imgPrev: newPostImageBool});
    };

    imageChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                selectedFile: file,
                prevImgURL: reader.result
            });
        }
        if(file) reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    id="new_post_image"
                    type="file"
                    onChange={this.imageChange}
                    name="image"
                    accept="image/*"
                />

                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => this.imagePreview(true)}
                    className="btn btn-info btn-lg"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#myModal"
                >
                    Preview Image
                </button>

                {this.state.imgPrev ?
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 className="modal-title">Preview</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <img id="pic" className="img-responsive" src={this.state.prevImgURL}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Upload;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            prevImgURL: '',
            imgPrev: false
        };
        this.imageChange = this.imageChange.bind(this);
    }

    imagePreview = (newPostImageBool) => {
        this.setState({imgPrev: newPostImageBool});
    };

    closeModal = () =>  {
        this.setState({imgPrev : false});
    };

    imageChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                selectedFile: file,
                prevImgURL: reader.result
            });
        }
        if(file) reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <input
                id="new_post_image"
                type="file"
                onChange={this.imageChange}
                name="image"
                accept="image/*"
            />

            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.imagePreview(true)}
                className="btn btn-info btn-lg"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal"
            >
                Preview Image
            </button>

            {!!this.state.imgPrev &&
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>&times;</button>
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Preview</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <img id="pic" className="img-responsive" src={this.state.prevImgURL}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             }
        </div>
       );
   }
}

export default Upload;
```

Comment: why are you using `!!`?

Comment: Just a habbit of old style, it can work without also.

Comment: thanks man, I appreciate it.  Sometimes I feel down because I can't solve the simple problems.  As a junior developer, it has me stuck in imposter syndrome purgatory.  Is it this normal?

Comment: It is normal even for people who spent years in development. Programming is all about solving problems and experience you get and one of the most mistakes people make is to give up. Never give up, learn gradually without too much stress. Here in this problem you had based on the value of bool variable your modal is rendered or not, so especially in javascript things can get frustrating but it's all part of job - just don't give up. I sometimes waiste days not seeing the most obvious thing. Just as long as you understood solution you are good to go next time you have similar. :)